# Try catch exceptional handling

Tags: java

I have been trying using the Arraylist, but that dint seem to work
I need one simple example for index out of bound exception handling using the try catch blocks in java

This is my code, how do I integrate with try catch blocks to handle the exception?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class NewClass2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> lis = new ArrayList<>();
        lis.add("My");
        lis.add("Name");
        // in the next line, an IndexOutOfBoundsException occurs
        System.out.println(lis.get(2));
    }
}
```

Can I also get an example for Illegal Argument exception using the try catch

Comment: You don't typically handle that exception. That fact that you're getting that exception almost certainly means that you have a bug in your code. You need to prevent the error from happening, not cover it up with a try/catch.

Comment: I need example for  Illegal argument exception as well

Comment: What have you tried? what is going wrong? what error do you get?

Comment: import java.util.ArrayList;
public class NewClass2
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ArrayList<String> lis = new ArrayList<>();
        lis.add("My");
        lis.add("Name");
        System.out.println(lis.get(2));
    }
}
This is my code.. how do I integrate with try catch blocks to handle the exception

Comment: There are only 2 items in that list, and indexes start from 0. `lis.get(0)` or `lis.get(1)` would work.

Comment: "This is my code" Don't put it in a comment, it is basically impossible to read: [edit] your question.

Comment: please put your code in code blocks in the question, instead of in a comment.

Comment: done! Please have a look

Comment: https://www.google.co.in/search?q=how+to+use+try+catch+in+java&oq=how+to+use+try+ca&aqs=chrome.2.69i57j0l5.4208j1j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: @AndyTurner is right. Arrays and Collections are 0-based in Java. Meaning that for an ArrayList with n elements, the valid indices are 0 to (n-1)

Comment: @Ravalikasai what exactly do you think "to catch an exception" means? if I follow a statement you commented an answer on, you think that if an error message is shown on the screen, that means that the exception is not caught. That is not true at all. Please, read up on error handling, and see what catching an Exception means

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Don't** try to use try/catch blocks to catch the exception. You can check if the index you are trying to pass is negative, or greater than or equal to the size, and avoid the exception ever being thrown in the first place.

As described in [the Javadoc of `ArrayList.get(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html):

> [Throws] `IndexOutOfBoundsException` - if the index is out of range `(index < 0 || index >= size())`

So, just check this in your code:

```
if (i >= 0 && i < lis.size()) {
  // Do something for an index in bounds.
} else {
  // Do something for an index out of bounds.
}
```

Only use exception handling for cases which you cannot avoid by checking in advance. This is covered in detail in *Effective Java*; in the 2nd Ed this is Item 57: "Use exceptions only for exceptional conditions".

Comment: And what is 'i' in (i >= 0 && i < lis.size())

Comment: @surendrapanday the index of the item you are trying to retrieve, e.g. 2. If the index is a literal, you obviously don't need to check `2 >= 0`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a basic example:

```
int[] num = {1, 3, 4, 5};

try {
    System.out.println(num[30]);
}

catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
    e.printStackTrace(System.out);
}
```

And for an ArrayList:

```
try {
    ArrayList<String> lis = new ArrayList<String>();
    lis.add("My");
    lis.add("Name"); System.out.println(lis.get(2));
    }

catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        e.printStackTrace(System.out);
    }
```

Comment: Downvote is puzzling. I tested the code, and 5,000 hours of Anki studying Java Arrays later... I can tell you that this is correct. I just looked directly in the book, and have memorized it at this point. This is how you handle the exception... I can send the down voter a reference.

Comment: The exception is not caught using the code you modified. The error msg is shown in the console

Comment: Yes it is. I printed the stack trace in my console. I just tested it. It prints a String of the StackTrace

Comment: @Ravalikasai the error message being shown does not mean the exception isn't caught

Comment: Yes it does. It’s called exception handling. The exception is being caught within the catch block. I mean I’m not making this up. I can send you a picture from my console. The catch block is literally catching the exception and handling it by printing the stack trace.

Comment: This is totally correct

Comment: ok.. convincing, I can also get an example for illegal argument exception using the same try and catch blocks

Comment: You won’t be able to print the stacktrace unless you catch the exception though. So you aren’t handling the illegal argument exception. The Java runtime is

Comment: Instead of `e.printStackTrace(System.out)` write `System.out.println("Exception caught");` and you will be convinced it's working

Comment: @Ravalikasai to get the other Exception as well, there are several ways. do you want them to be handled differently, in an identical way, ... ?

Comment: Yep. Or he can try System.err.printlin(e), or any String he wants to enter, and he will see the exception is being caught. The other exceptions that you aren’t catching Ravalika are being caught by the Java Runtime

Comment: It is working now, Thanks.
Similarly I want another example for Illegal Argument Exception

Answer (score 0):

As many people already stated, you are trying to access the third element (index = 2, indexes start at 0) of a data structure that has only 2 elements.

However, you could apply `try`-`catch` for this like the following, for example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<String> lis = new ArrayList<>();
    lis.add("My");
    lis.add("Name");
    // now you just try the access
    try {
        System.out.println(lis.get(2));
    // and especially handle the IndexOutOfBoundsException
    } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException ex) {
        System.err.println("You are trying to access an index that is not available (out of bounds)!");
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```